# Three js 3d model loaders

Tags: javascript, three.js

All the last latest versions of threejs use es6 for most everything. I need the object loaders for obj, fbx, gftl in normal js code. Are they available or can someone convert them for me?

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

> Are they available or can someone convert them for me?

If you need a ES6 to ES5 conversion, you have to setup the transpiling workflow by yourself.

> in normal js code

According to current JavaScript standards, ES6 features like class syntax or `let`/`const` is "normal" JavaScript code.

Comment: I understand those but it’s more setting the JavaScript to module type which then breaks other code on page from being able to access that. Also imports would be a bit tricky as well

Comment: You can try to re-generate the files in [example/js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js) which are no ES6 modules but global scripts via `npm run build-examples`. By adjusting the [Babel configuration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/utils/build/.babelrc.json) you should be able to generate ES5 code.

Comment: Thanks for the help